# Loop collapsing in Ruby - iterating through combinations of two ranges

Tags: ruby

I have a code that iterates through two ranges. Please see the example below:

```
(0..6).each do |wday|
  (0..23).each do |hour|
    p [wday,hour]
  end
end
```

Although this seems very concise and readable, sometimes 5 lines can be too much. One might want to write a more vertically compact code.

```
(0..6).to_a.product((0..23).to_a).each do |wday,hour|
  p [wday, hour]
end
```

Above was my try, but the code looks very artificial to me. Am I missing something? Does ruby have a preferred way for this type of loop collapsing? If not, are there other alternatives to this workaround?

Comment: I would write the two loops. It is clearer, it is (I believe) more performant, and quite Rubyish. There is no downside except for taking two more lines; which leads me to ask - why do you care about the number of lines so much?

Comment: The loop itself should be a smidgeon faster. The whole non-lazy instantiation of ranges with Carthesian product is a pure waste. And while you could write an enumerator for a carthesian product of two enumerables, it itself would have to be implemented with nested loops, so you win nothing, performance-wise (unless you make it a native code extension).

Comment: It is not a tradeoff: you need the same amount of iterations to *construct* the big array in the first place. So it's not time vs space: it's time vs (time+space), unless you're going to reuse the big array many times. `ruby -rbenchmark -e "puts Benchmark.measure { 50.times { s = 0; [*0..1000].product([*0..1000]) { |i, j| s+= i * j } } }"`: 7.48s. `ruby -rbenchmark -e "puts Benchmark.measure { 50.times { s = 0; (0..1000).each { |i| (0..1000).each { |j| s+= i * j } } } }"`: 3.66s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is slightly cleaner version of your loop:

```
[*0..6].product([*0..23]).each do |wday,hour|
  p [wday, hour]
end
```

This approach does have the disadvantage of expanding the ranges into memory.

I think my preferred way of "collapsing" loops though, especially if the specific loop structure occurs in multiple places, is to turn the nested loops into a method that takes a block and `yield`s to it. E.g.

```
def for_each_hour_in_week
  (0..6).each do |wday|
    (0..23).each do |hour|
      yield wday,hour
    end
  end
end

for_each_hour_in_week do |wday,hour|
  p [wday,hour]
end
```

This keeps the deep nesting out of the way of your logic, and makes your intent clear.

Comment: Both of your suggestions are extremely useful. Looks like good things can happen sometimes in sof even when I ask a not-so-great question.